# Internal Links with jQuery Address

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history, deep-linking, hashbang

I'm trying to implement the lovely Address plugin to handle internal links for prettier links and use of the back button. I managed to get it to work, however the one thing I noticed, is that when it changes the URL from /#section to /#/section if the user then copies that URL and tries to open it in a new window (or send to a friend) it does not take the user to that section on the page. Obviously because it's not recognized as an anchor anymore.

How can I get it to be on the right section when a user navigates via the URL?

Below is the snippet of code I'm using in accordance with jQuery Address:

```
$('nav a').click(function() { 
    var pageTitle = 'Kevin Dare Foundation | ' + $(this).html(); 
    $.address.value($(this).attr('href').replace(/^#/, ''));
    $.address.title(pageTitle);
});
```

Also here is the link to see it in action: http://nickdimatteo.com/kjd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way may be to trigger the code you have when the document loads if there is a document.location.hash:

```
$('nav a').click(function() { 
    var pageTitle = 'Kevin Dare Foundation | ' + $(this).html(); 
    $.address.value($(this).attr('href').replace(/^#/, ''));
    $.address.title(pageTitle);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = document.location.hash.replace(/^#\//, '');
    if(hash) {
        $('nav a[href="#' + hash + '"]').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Comment: This works great. Is there a way to have it be on the section on page load, rather than loading the page and scrolling to the desired section?

Comment: To do that, you would need to adjust your Address plugin change callback to animate the scroll much faster. There would need to be some kind of state variable to let it know whether to animate slow or fast.